# Tensorflow, embedding representation issues, false nearest neighbours

Tags: tensorflow, space, tensorboard, embedding

I'm using TensorBoard to visualise the embedding space but when I try to find the nearest neighbours for a single point, it seems that they are not the good ones. I've a very good accuracy when I just create a Tree with `special.CKTree` and take the nearest neighbours with `tree.query()`

Is it a way to be sure that the point I'm selecting correspond to the right embedding vector ? Has somebody the same issue ?

Thanks a lot